# Can't find `weblogic.Server` when running WebLogic from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

```
/Users/zzw/Middleware/wls1036/domain/startWebLogic.sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Users/zzw/Middleware/wls1036/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/Users/zzw/Middleware/wls1036/wlserver/server/lib/wljmxclient.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/weblogicIntegration.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-impl.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/openapi.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/specifics/weblogicSpecifics.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 49987 com.intellij.javaee.weblogic.agent.WebLogicAgent9
Detected server http port: 7001
.
java version "1.7.0_80"
.
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar:/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/wlserver/server/lib/xqrl.jar
.
PATH=/wlserver/server/bin:/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http://hostname:port/console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Starting WLS with line:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Name=myserver -Djava.security.policy=/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50485,suspend=y,server=n  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=/wlserver -Dwls.home=/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/wlserver/server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=  weblogic.Server
[2017-05-04 12:05:31,905] Artifact shuangdeng:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50485', transport: 'socket'
错误: 找不到或无法加载主类 weblogic.Server
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50485', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from server
```

Error: can't find or load class `weblogic.Server`.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you would have the same problem if you started the server manually outside of IDEA, so it is not actually an IDEA problem.

Please check environment variables (PATH and CLASSPATH) in your startWebLogic.sh, apparently the server had been moved to `/Users/zzw/Middleware/...` while they are still pointing to `/wlserver/server/...`.

Comment: thank you!! that is environment variables problem, i fixed。but i have a new  problem, can i use `shiro` run in weblogic. so many exption about `shiro`